# Uninstalled kali-tools icons not removed from menu

Tags: katoolin

I use ubuntu 19.04. I've uninstalled all kali-tools that were installed with katoolin, but I can see those icons in the menu. How can I remove those?

Thanks

Comment: Has someone Any idea?

Comment: Do they launch apps or something when clicked?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes, They launch when I click on icons.

Comment: Then they haven't uninstalled yet. Identify that packages and remove them manually.